# Displayed SQL rows being limited for reason with JOINED tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

I have the following code to perform a dynamic query of JOINED tables but for some reason, whenever I try to display the row, it only displays up the first 9 rows then stops.

```
$query = "SELECT `results`, `Success`, `Failure`, `Counter`, `Grades`, `Classes`,
`Special_Id`, `SpecialCondition` FROM `Courses` INNER JOIN `Students` ON `id` = 
`Students_Id`";
```

And this is how I'm fetching the rows and displaying them:

```
<?php
foreach($results as $row){
echo $row['grades'].'<br />';
}
```

I tested the JOIN SQL syntax in phpMyAdmin and while it returns as a positive task, I notice that it only shows the original table and not the joined table after being joined.

Any suggestions on where i'm going wrong here? I'm only showing this portion of the code because everything works fine, and when I remove the JOIN syntax it works beautifully, so I'm lead to believe the joining is causing the issue but I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

EDITED TO SHOW SQL SCHEMA:

Sure, Hopefully the following helps.

```
Table: Courses
id (PK)| results | Success | Failure | Counter | Grades | Classes |
1        Posted      1         0         2        B+         2
2        Pending     0         0         1        NA         1
3        Posted      0         1         3        F          1
4
5
6
7
8
9
10+

Table: Students
Students_Id (PK) | FirstName | LastName |
     1              Chris        Test
     2               Jen         Test   
     3
     4  
     5
     6
     7
     8
     9
     10+
```

To keep things easy to read, I removed the information in the other 10+ rows, but there is data populating them.

Also, I noticed in the OP, I'm selecting "Special_Id and SpecialConditions". That's actually wrong. I'm not selecting those fields anymore.

When joining tables, does every column have to have data in-order to successfully INNER JOIN or can there be empty rows as well?

Comment: Could you add the database schema to the question?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your schema. Course 1 belongs to Student Chris, Course 2 to Jen and so on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query shows that you are joining where the `id` from the `Courses` table matches the `Students_Id` from `Students`.  However, the schema makes it look as though `id` is not actually a student identifier but rather just a record index in that table.  It seems to me that you need to have an additional column in `Courses` for the key to the `Students` table.

> I tested the JOIN SQL syntax in phpMyAdmin and while it returns as a positive task, I notice that it only shows the original table and not the joined table after being joined.

Note that you only told the query to select columns that were included in the `Courses` table.  You probably also wanted to select `Students.FirstName` and `Students.LastName` (or something similar).

Comment: Ah, I see now. I was completely forgetting the (FK) and good point regarding the selection bit, I didn't even think about it. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2):

When joining tables, your join condition must be met by the row for the join to complete. In this case, it's an inner join, so it throws out any rows where the join conditions are not met.

My first point I'd make to you is to use table aliases, like so:

```
SELECT 
    c.results, 
    c.Success, 
    c.Failure, 
    c.Counter, 
    c.Grades, 
    c.Classes
FROM 
    Courses c
    INNER JOIN Students s ON 
        c.id = s.Students_Id
```

The second thing I'd mention is that your database design is a little worrisome. Firstly, why are you joining the `id` column of `Courses` to the `Students_ID` column of `Students`? Unless, of course, they're one-to-one (since they're a PK of their respective tables). If that's the case, then they should really just be one table.

However, if the `Grades` column has any `null` values in it, you'll either get a line break displayed (with your PHP script), or it may error out (it's been awhile since I did PHP scripting). It's best to check this in a MySQL query tool first.

Comment: Hey Eric, your answer was definitely helpful, but I went with Michael's above because he pinpointed my lamebrained issue. Thanks for your help though, I greatly appreciated it. Also, I did my DB that way because my intention was to break it all down for cardinality later on. I just forgot the (FK) for relational purposes. I'll definitely take your advice on using aliases :)